# Laptop not connecting through ethernet cable

Tags: windows-7, networking, laptop, linux-mint, cable

My Compaq Presario CQ60 laptop with a dual boot of Linux Mint and Windows 7 is not connecting with my ethernet cable. Wireless does still work. The laptop does not connect through an ethernet cable at a friend's place also, so I think it is something with my laptop.

The facts:

> With both Windows and Linux no connection possible.
>
> On Windows the laptop does stay that a network connection is identified. After five seconds it then says that there is no access to the network.
>
> The provider states that everything is fine although I did "lose a lot of packages".
>
> While starting up the computer on the first screen on the upper left it says "Serial number not found" (this is new I believe)
>
> Resetting the BIOS did not work.
>
> Shutting down, removing the battery, waiting for 30 minutes and restarting did not work.

I hope someone can provide suggestions as of what can be wrong and how it can be fixed.

Comment: Check your TCP/IP configuration. Did you specify an IP address? Maybe you assigned an address that is the same on both Wireless and Ethernet interface?

Comment: How do I do this? (And could this be the issue if both Windows and Linux do not work?)

Comment: 1) Kinda obvious, but if you were using the same cable both places, try a different cable.  2) Examine the socket closely, and look for any damage.  3) Make sure the cable is going all the way in to the socket.  4) Try turning off the WiFi adapter, if you can.

Comment: And you ARE using a 6-wire cable in the RJ45 socket, right?  Not a 4-wire cable in the modem socket?

Comment: The cable used to work fine so it is the right cable. Also using the cable of a neighbor with the same internet and cable (student flat) does not solve the problem.

Comment: by 'cable' do you mean ethernet? In most cases, cable internet can also mean DOCSIS modems.

Comment: Oops -- I meant *8-wire* cable.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I do indeed mean ethernet cable! I've changed the question.

Comment: @DanielRHicks: heh, I've seen 4 wire ethernet cable bundled with a homeplug AV device, so... entirely plausible too ;p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting link lights, then you can attempt to reset your ip configuration.  Its simple but sometimes thats all it takes.

Go into CMD and run

```
ipconfig/release
```

once that runs

```
ipconfig/renew
```

if that doesnt help run:  `ipconfig` and see if it is giving a no media connected error or something similar.  If it isnt the cable and the connection is set up fine it could be the hardware on the 10/100 port.

Comment: Thanks! I will try this once I get home. I found an old router at my parents' place which is a "solution" as well so the problem is solved. Merry Christmas. :-)